# SQL Server 2012: Calculating total time elapsed for every unique record from a logs table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to implement a very complex function using SQL and I can't figure out where to start.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Entity | Source |Destination |  Time
--------------------------------------------------------
E1     |   -    |  T12       |2012-05-17 10:13:01.000
E2     |   -    |  T22       |2012-05-17 10:13:02.000
E1     |   T12  |  T22       |2012-05-17 10:13:03.000
E2     |   T22  |  T12       |2012-05-17 10:13:04.000
E1     |   T22  |  T12       |2012-05-17 10:13:05.000
E2     |   T12  |  T21       |2012-05-17 10:13:06.000
E1     |   T12  |  T13       |2012-05-17 10:13:07.000
E2     |   T21  |  T23       |2012-05-17 10:13:08.000

---------------------------------------------------
Src/Dest | Type
---------------------------------------------------
   T11   | T1
   T12   | T1  
   T13   | T1 
   T21   | T2       
   T22   |  T2
   T23   |  T2
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I need to calculate total time spent by each entity in both the types.

For example:

E1 has spent 2sec(13:01-13:03) in T12, 2sec(13:03-13:05) in T22, 2sec(13:05-13:07) in T12. So, time spent in T1 is 4 seconds and time spent in T2 is 2 seconds

E2 has spent 2sec(13:02-13:04) in T22, 2sec(13:04-13:06) in T12, 2sec(13:06-13:08) in T21. So, time spent in T1 is 2 seconds and time spent in T2 is 4 seconds.

Note: I cannot do maximum - minimum time; I need to keep on accumulating time till there is no record available.

What would be the easiest way to do this in SQL Server 2012? I can create any intermediate tables, if it is required. Thanks!

Comment: So it's considered 'in' a type from the time it's listed as the destination to the time it's listed in the source?

Comment: Yes, that would be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
SELECT Entity,Destination'Type',Time,SUM(TimeDiff) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity, Destination ORDER BY Time)'Running Total'
FROM (SELECT Entity, LEFT(SOURCE,2)'Source',LEFT(Destination,2)'Destination',Time, DATEDIFF(second,LAG([Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity ORDER BY [Time]),[time])'TimeDiff'
        FROM  #test
     )sub
ORDER BY TIME
```

Or if you just want the total time for a given Entity/Type combination:

```
SELECT Entity, Type, MAX(Running_Total)
FROM (SELECT Entity,Destination'Type',Time,SUM(TimeDiff) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity, Destination ORDER BY Time)'Running_Total'
      FROM (SELECT Entity, LEFT(SOURCE,2)'Source',LEFT(Destination,2)'Destination',Time, DATEDIFF(second,LAG([Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity ORDER BY [Time]),[time])'TimeDiff'
              FROM  Table1
           )sub
      )sub
GROUP BY Entity, Type
ORDER BY Entity, Type
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65ceb/8/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of Lag function, and it took some for me to figure out. But seems like it will work. Thanks again.